Установка драйвера amd на ubuntu с ошибкой
Сейчас сижу на ubuntu 24.04, и проблема: не устанавливается драйвер ubuntu на видеокарту rx 5700 xt (Через amdgpu-install) с ошибкой:
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code 
А этот драйвер для ubuntu 22.04.И опциональные настройки не спасают Как всё-кати установить драйвер на rx 5700 xt без перестановки ubuntu на более младшую версию
